# Generators of Finite Cyclic Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a cyclic multiplicative group such as $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ where $p$ is prime, how do you determine an element in that group that generates the entire group?

Comment: Those generators are called _primitive roots_.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_p$ is *not* a multiplicative group.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the *additive* group $\mathbb{Z}_n$, then you are looking for an element with order $n$.  Try different values of $n$ and see what elements generate $\mathbb{Z}_n$.  See if you can show that an element $a\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ has order $n$ if and only if $(a,n)=1$.

In general, you can show that an element $a$ has order $\frac{n}{(a,n)}$.

Now, if you mean the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$, then this is only cyclic when $n=2,4,p^k,$ or $2p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime.  In that case, classifying the generators is an open problem.  You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).

Comment: If course, once you've found a generator for $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ you can easily find a generator for $\mathbb Z_{p^k}^\times$. The key problem is generators for $\mathbb Z_p^\times$

Answer (score 2):

Aside from obvious exclusions, such as perfect squares, it is hard to say much about how to find primitive roots in $\mathbb Z_p^\times$. They are distinctly badly behaved. Trial and error is about as good as you can get.

The first paragraph in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1992-58-197/S0025-5718-1992-1106981-9/S0025-5718-1992-1106981-9.pdf) gives a rough outline. The next paragraph indicates a result known *if* the extended Riemann Hypothesis is true, which indicates the kind of complexity we are dealing with. (Note: In that paper, $\textrm{GF}(p)\cong\mathbb Z_p$.)